# Upload a container to registry V2 using API (2.5.1)

Tags: api, curl, docker, docker-registry

*Hi, I'm trying to upload a docker container to a private docker registry using the API.*

Using docker command everything seems to works just fine:

```
docker pull ubuntu:16.04
docker tag ubuntu:16.04 <PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/ubuntu/16.04
docker push <PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/ubuntu/16.04
```

I'm trying to upload the same image using the API, what I've done:

- export the container using `docker save ubuntu:16.04 -o ubuntu.tar`
- untar the container file `tar xf ubuntu.tar`
- upload all the layers with curl
- upload manifest with curl

Ok, reading [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), the layers must be PUT separatedly each one with their digest obtained using `sha256sum <LAYER-FILE>` and after it's done, manifest should be also `PUT` onto registry

**curl call details :)**

```
curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["318d5752-b10b-49da-9ebf-5891b679a805"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:53 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/318d5752-b10b-49da-9ebf-5891b679a805?_state\u003dv2nk-ATsPGQKJatyjUQTSJwl2BlQywrqeCkVTzQj0uh7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiMzE4ZDU3NTItYjEwYi00OWRhLTllYmYtNTg5MWI2NzlhODA1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjE1Njk5NzUxM1oifQ%3D%3D"]}
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/3e1722599d1d5331b610200b6b41f895759e312ff1f14e009bee2f52f962b69f/layer.tar)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/3e1722599d1d5331b610200b6b41f895759e312ff1f14e009bee2f52f962b69f/layer.tar http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/318d5752-b10b-49da-9ebf-5891b679a805?_state=v2nk-ATsPGQKJatyjUQTSJwl2BlQywrqeCkVTzQj0uh7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiMzE4ZDU3NTItYjEwYi00OWRhLTllYmYtNTg5MWI2NzlhODA1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjE1Njk5NzUxM1oifQ%3D%3D&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:53 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:bf6751561805be7d07d66f6acb2a33e99cf0cc0a20f5fd5d94a3c7f8ae55c2a1"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:bf6751561805be7d07d66f6acb2a33e99cf0cc0a20f5fd5d94a3c7f8ae55c2a1"]}

curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["7680a9d6-7686-49a6-a6fa-44979370c2ec"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:53 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/7680a9d6-7686-49a6-a6fa-44979370c2ec?_state\u003duyI8QOIktlkc_9qynIKOXJC0FaVT6YQPlpRGfwNXHgV7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiNzY4MGE5ZDYtNzY4Ni00OWE2LWE2ZmEtNDQ5NzkzNzBjMmVjIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjU3NDc3ODk3OVoifQ%3D%3D"]}
code: $1
body:$2
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/6f12534822c57808e10e079842da48607c40eeb82048541320ba454af83cf021/layer.tar)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/6f12534822c57808e10e079842da48607c40eeb82048541320ba454af83cf021/layer.tar http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/7680a9d6-7686-49a6-a6fa-44979370c2ec?_state=uyI8QOIktlkc_9qynIKOXJC0FaVT6YQPlpRGfwNXHgV7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiNzY4MGE5ZDYtNzY4Ni00OWE2LWE2ZmEtNDQ5NzkzNzBjMmVjIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjU3NDc3ODk3OVoifQ%3D%3D&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:53 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:943edb549a8300092a714190dfe633341c0ffb483784c4fdfe884b9019f6a0b4"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:943edb549a8300092a714190dfe633341c0ffb483784c4fdfe884b9019f6a0b4"]}

curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["8b7245b4-9f42-42e6-8512-6b645ac233a0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:54 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/8b7245b4-9f42-42e6-8512-6b645ac233a0?_state\u003dg5hAehwCOPnnMhfUC-Ugu_-lX9pp5NgJdTjB7cp0hO57Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiOGI3MjQ1YjQtOWY0Mi00MmU2LTg1MTItNmI2NDVhYzIzM2EwIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjk4NDA1OTE4N1oifQ%3D%3D"]}
code: $1
body:$2
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/23a78ada034808b66348c42b9bb941901651b533b445cfb94e6b7646d2e2110d/layer.tar)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/23a78ada034808b66348c42b9bb941901651b533b445cfb94e6b7646d2e2110d/layer.tar http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/8b7245b4-9f42-42e6-8512-6b645ac233a0?_state=g5hAehwCOPnnMhfUC-Ugu_-lX9pp5NgJdTjB7cp0hO57Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiOGI3MjQ1YjQtOWY0Mi00MmU2LTg1MTItNmI2NDVhYzIzM2EwIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjUzLjk4NDA1OTE4N1oifQ%3D%3D&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:54 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:c1bd37d01c89de343d68867518b1155cb297d8e03942066ecb44ae8f46b608a3"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:c1bd37d01c89de343d68867518b1155cb297d8e03942066ecb44ae8f46b608a3"]}

curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["8d97ab31-5801-4bdd-bdfd-a4878b9e7317"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:05:55 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/8d97ab31-5801-4bdd-bdfd-a4878b9e7317?_state\u003d0NkM--lD5vDA_wlPiPd1dEs-7WwDSmb_UfGJmMDAsIR7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiOGQ5N2FiMzEtNTgwMS00YmRkLWJkZmQtYTQ4NzhiOWU3MzE3IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjU1LjE5MDY1NDkzWiJ9"]}
code: $1
body:$2
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/a940c634b64a460f47e4c5d6f51e49c28280eb9e0e3da24df76b00c8c60ba756/layer.tar)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/a940c634b64a460f47e4c5d6f51e49c28280eb9e0e3da24df76b00c8c60ba756/layer.tar http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/8d97ab31-5801-4bdd-bdfd-a4878b9e7317?_state=0NkM--lD5vDA_wlPiPd1dEs-7WwDSmb_UfGJmMDAsIR7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiOGQ5N2FiMzEtNTgwMS00YmRkLWJkZmQtYTQ4NzhiOWU3MzE3IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA1OjU1LjE5MDY1NDkzWiJ9&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:07 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:e7ebc6e16708285bee3917ae12bf8d172ee0d7684a7830751ab9a1c070e7a125"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:e7ebc6e16708285bee3917ae12bf8d172ee0d7684a7830751ab9a1c070e7a125"]}


curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["bb5ccb7c-4bf2-4a80-a78f-36cd01d139a5"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:08 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/bb5ccb7c-4bf2-4a80-a78f-36cd01d139a5?_state\u003dLyO6bZxCT0B1bfJXxnwVnsRmshIZgDvAr9VdREmmOEB7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiYmI1Y2NiN2MtNGJmMi00YTgwLWE3OGYtMzZjZDAxZDEzOWE1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA2OjA3Ljk5NDA4MjYzNFoifQ%3D%3D"]}
code: $1
body:$2
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/b7f0f1a6360ea96cc4ec0a3a28aaf8a385807ed42ceb372cd46d08d12711ad45/layer.tar)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/b7f0f1a6360ea96cc4ec0a3a28aaf8a385807ed42ceb372cd46d08d12711ad45/layer.tar http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/bb5ccb7c-4bf2-4a80-a78f-36cd01d139a5?_state=LyO6bZxCT0B1bfJXxnwVnsRmshIZgDvAr9VdREmmOEB7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiYmI1Y2NiN2MtNGJmMi00YTgwLWE3OGYtMzZjZDAxZDEzOWE1IiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA2OjA3Ljk5NDA4MjYzNFoifQ%3D%3D&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:08 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:f934e33a54a60630267df295a5c232ceb15b2938ebb0476364192b1537449093"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:f934e33a54a60630267df295a5c232ceb15b2938ebb0476364192b1537449093"]}


curl -XPOST -H 'accept: application/json' http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/
response headers: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"Docker-Upload-Uuid":["55b5d57c-4169-4884-8068-cf3a79fc8cef"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Range":["0-0"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:08 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/55b5d57c-4169-4884-8068-cf3a79fc8cef?_state\u003dy3gKd9CDD-Auw_mast0ki4dzXrO1vsnUOvv7eqZIgRl7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiNTViNWQ1N2MtNDE2OS00ODg0LTgwNjgtY2YzYTc5ZmM4Y2VmIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA2OjA4LjQwNDQ5ODcwM1oifQ%3D%3D"]}
code: $1
body:$2
DIGEST=$(sha256sum /home/user/container/ubuntu/e4415b714b624040f19f45994b51daed5cbdb00e0eb9a07221ff0bd6bcf55ed7.json)
curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/e4415b714b624040f19f45994b51daed5cbdb00e0eb9a07221ff0bd6bcf55ed7.json http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/55b5d57c-4169-4884-8068-cf3a79fc8cef?_state=y3gKd9CDD-Auw_mast0ki4dzXrO1vsnUOvv7eqZIgRl7Ik5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0MDEiLCJVVUlEIjoiNTViNWQ1N2MtNDE2OS00ODg0LTgwNjgtY2YzYTc5ZmM4Y2VmIiwiT2Zmc2V0IjowLCJTdGFydGVkQXQiOiIyMDE2LTExLTIzVDE2OjA2OjA4LjQwNDQ5ODcwM1oifQ%3D%3D&digest=sha256:${DIGEST}
code: 201
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:08 GMT"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset\u003dutf-8"],"Location":["http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:e4415b714b624040f19f45994b51daed5cbdb00e0eb9a07221ff0bd6bcf55ed7"],"Docker-Content-Digest":["sha256:e4415b714b624040f19f45994b51daed5cbdb00e0eb9a07221ff0bd6bcf55ed7"]}

curl -XPUT -H 'accept: application/json' -d @/home/user/container/ubuntu/manifest.json http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/manifests/16.04
code: 400
body: {"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version":["registry/2.0"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"Content-Length":["118"],"Date":["Wed, 23 Nov 2016 16:06:08 GMT"],"Content-Type":["application/json; charset\u003dutf-8"]}
{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_INVALID","message":"manifest invalid","detail":{"Value":"array","Type":{},"Offset":1}}]}
```

I've also tried to generate a manual manifest with the minimal content but also get error from the manifest PUT:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "name": "ubuntu",
  "tag": "16.04",
  "fsLayers": [
    {"blobSum": "sha256:bf6751561805be7d07d66f6acb2a33e99cf0cc0a20f5fd5d94a3c7f8ae55c2a1"},
    {"blobSum": "sha256:943edb549a8300092a714190dfe633341c0ffb483784c4fdfe884b9019f6a0b4"},
    {"blobSum": "sha256:c1bd37d01c89de343d68867518b1155cb297d8e03942066ecb44ae8f46b608a3"},
    {"blobSum": "sha256:e7ebc6e16708285bee3917ae12bf8d172ee0d7684a7830751ab9a1c070e7a125"},
    {"blobSum": "sha256:f934e33a54a60630267df295a5c232ceb15b2938ebb0476364192b1537449093"}
  ]
}
```

Other details:
docker registry version :

```
registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.5.1
```

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Tue, 27 Sep 2016 12:25:38 +1300
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Tue, 27 Sep 2016 12:25:38 +1300
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

I found only one article really describing this, which works.

https://www.danlorenc.com/post/containers-part-2/

The article describes to create and upload one layer with V1 config and Manifest to google registry, but it's a good base to learn the concept.

I'll put the concept down in case the website disappears, all credit to the author `github.com/dlorenc` of that article.

Basicly before creating your manifest, you need to create a v1+json config, and upload it as a blob, where the V1+json config contains the layers with the digest of the content, not the blob.

```
cat <<EOF > config.json
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created_by": "Bash!"
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:$(gunzip layer.tar.gz --to-stdout | shasum -a 256 | cut -d' ' -f1)"
    ]
  }
}
EOF
```

With the config and layer in place, you can define the manifest:

```
# We need to know the size and digest of our layer and config:
size=$(wc -c layer.tar.gz | awk '{print $1}')
digest="sha256:$(shasum -a 256 layer.tar.gz | cut -d' ' -f1)"
config_size=$(wc -c config.json | awk '{print $1}')
config_digest="sha256:$(shasum -a 256 config.json | cut -d' ' -f1)"

cat << EOF > manifest.json
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": $config_size,
    "digest": "$config_digest"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": $size,
      "digest": "$digest"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

Now you can upload your layers:

```
# Check to see if the layer exists:
returncode=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" \
            -o /dev/null \
            -I http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/$digest)

if [[ $returncode -ne 200  ]]; then
    # Start the upload and get the location header.
    # The HTTP response seems to include carriage returns, which we need to strip
    location=$(curl -i -X POST \
               http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/ \
               -d "" | grep Location | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d '\r')

    # Do the upload
    curl -X PUT $location\?digest=$digest --data-binary @layer.tar.gz
fi
```

Upload Config, basicly same code as for the layer:

```
returncode=$(curl -w "%{http_code}" -o /dev/null \
    -I http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/$config_digest)

if [[ $returncode -ne 200  ]]; then
    # Start the upload and get the location header.
    # The HTTP response seems to include carriage returns, which we need to strip
    location=$(curl -i -X POST \
        http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/blobs/uploads/ \ 
     -d "" | grep Location | cut -d" " -f2 | tr -d '\r')

    # Do the upload
    curl -X PUT $location\?digest=$config_digest --data-binary @config.json
fi
```

and TAG your image by pushing the manifest:

```
curl -X PUT \
    http://<PRIVATE-REGISTRY-IP>:5000/v2/ubuntu/manifests/16.04 --data-binary @manifest.json
```

*Remark*

- example code does not do the authorisation.
- Does not work on the `openshift online starter` internal-registry (400 invalid manifest)
- need manual redirect on `gitlab-registry` as it returns 400 with a location header for blobs `HEAD` and `GET`